# i ned to get the values which are lesser than 50 from a field

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I need to get the values which are less than 50 from a field "cost" so what shoud I do???`

```
{
"query" :              
    {
        "field" :"cost",                              
             {              
                "lt" : 50                           
             }            
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a range query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "cost": {
                "lt": 50
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Or you could use a range filter (the results will be cached).

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "cost": {
                        "lt": 50
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html

Comment: can you post your mapping and an example document?

Comment: Range query worked for me. But you should make sure in the mappings that this field is mapped as number using a proper analyzer.